# how to make file extensions to syntax highlighting in vim?

Tags: vim, vim-syntax-highlighting

I have `*.q` files ( that are very similar to other SQL ) and I want to make vim syntax highlight it in the same way as SQL.

Answer (score 4):

create a `~/.vim/ftdetect` directory if not existing.
create a `~/.vim/ftdetect/<new-file-type-extention>.vim` with content:

```
au BufRead,BufNewFile *.<new-file-type-extention> set filetype=<existing-file-type-extention>
```

Answer (score 2):

Include it in the `~/.vim/filetype.vim`, as described at [Vim FAQ 26.8](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/vim_faq.txt.html#faq-26.8):

```
" my filetype file
if exists("did_load_filetypes")
    finish
endif
augroup filetypedetect
    au! BufRead,BufNewFile *.x       setfiletype c
augroup END
```

For this case it would be changed to something like this:

```
    au! BufRead,BufNewFile *.q       setfiletype sql
```

Check `:help new-filetype` for additional details.