# How to configure vim to treat .es6 files as javascript files

Tags: vim, macvim

I'm using https://github.com/carlhuda/janus .

I'm doing Rails development and I have some JavaScript files where we are using es6 features. These files have extension `.es6`. So the files are named like `users.es6`.

How do I tell vim to treat files ending with `.es6` as JavaScript files so that I could get syntax highlighting.

I'm using macvim but I don't think that should matter.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30979880/

Answer (score 10):

Add this to your `.vimrc`:

```
au BufNewFile,BufRead *.es6 set filetype=javascript
```